# Skin depth and electromagnetic shielding

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

The term "[Skin Depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect)" refers to the the depth upto which current flows from the surface of an AC-current-carrying conductor. This depth is inversely related to the frequency of the current. Does this also mean that the cage required to completely block an electromagnetic radiation must be as thick as the skin depth? Think of the cage as an enclosure made of a conductor material.

Comment: If you want to achieve sufficient blocking, you would make the metal several skin depths deep (usually around 10 or so). Thankfully, the skin depth for most frequencies is rather thin, so we never have to make our shielding boxes very thick. Note, however, that this is only true for electric components of the field. If you have a quasistatic magnetic field, the skin depth in the metal is of little help to you.

Comment: @CuriousOne what is quasistatic magnetic field?

Comment: A slowly changing magnetic field. The problem with that is that in the near field, e.g. around a transformer, it can only generate very weak eddy currents that won't counteract it, so the assumptions of the skin depth calculation don't apply. In that case you need ferromagnetic shielding materials and even then it's often enough difficult to achieve the required shielding.

Comment: @CuriousOne 1) It seems slowly changing magnetic field refers to its frequency. What is the cutoff frequency for it to be called quasistatic? Would you say 100 MHz and above EMW  do not have quasistatic magnetic field? 2) Is there a criteria (formula) to determine what distance is near-field or far-field?

Comment: By slowly changing I mean something like 50/60Hz from a transformer. At 100MHz you are well in the regime where a first order calculation with the skin depth usually works well.

Comment: @CuriousOne "sufficient" for what? Ten skin depths attenuates the field by $4.5 \times 10^{-5}$. That's -87 dB. That's a *lot*.

Comment: @DanielSank: It sounds like a lot, but when you are sitting a couple of miles from a major airport and their radar hits your low-noise preamp, then it's hardly enough. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne indeed, which is why I ask "sufficient for what?".

Comment: @DanielSank: Sufficient for most engineering purposes. If you are trying to detect brain waves with SQUIDs, you will have to do a lot better... but then, I did explain that to the OP.

Comment: @DanielSank what is the relation between skin depths and attenuation?

Comment: @CuriousOne so for high frequency waves, will several skin depths attenuate magnetic field as well?  Is there a formula?

Comment: Field amplitude goes as $\exp \left( -x / d \right)$ where $x$ is the distance into the material and $d$ is the skin depth. Attenuation is often given in terms of power, so you would square the amplitude. Also, at high frequencies remember that electromagnetic waves have energy oscillating between electrical and magnetic. Therefore, with radiating fields there's always so electric field which causes current to flow and thus causes skin losses.

Comment: @DanielSank thanks, i can follow your calculations now.